# Use result from one subroutine in another for vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a subroutine that does a calculation for certain values. The primary input for this is via a numericupdown in a form. Once the numbers are entered in the form, the code uses it to calculate other values which are then used to create a graph.
I want the values from the first subroutine to be used by other subroutine which is plotting the graph.
Here is the code:

```
Public Sub GCalc()
    Dim iI As Integer      
    Dim iE As Integer      
    Dim iT As Integer       
    Dim dI, dE As Double   'For chart datapoints

    iI = INumericUpDown.Value
    iE = ENumericUpDown.Value

    iT = iI + iE

    dI = (iI / iT) * 100
    dE = (iE / iT) * 100

End Sub

Private Sub INumericUpDown_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles INumericUpDown.ValueChanged
    'Clear any existing datapoint for that series and add the new data point when the numericupdown value is changed.
    Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.Clear()
    Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddXY(0, dI)
End Sub
```

How do I get the value of `dI` from GCalc sub to INumericUpDown_ValueChanged?
I tried to go through the other posts but did not understand them. Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks for the help.

Miki

Comment: @DanielA.White - I did not understand that. Can you please explain a little? I am new to vb.net.

Comment: You only need the dI? or other values to?

Comment: @bugs2919 - Just dI in "INumericUpDown_ValueChanged". And then "dE" in "ENumericUpDown_ValueChanged".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return something from it - so you have to make it a `Function` instead.

```
Structure Result
   Public dI As Double
   Public dE As Double
End Structure
Public Function GCalc() As Result
    Dim iI As Integer      
    Dim iE As Integer      
    Dim iT As Integer       
    Dim dI, dE As Double   'For chart datapoints

    iI = INumericUpDown.Value
    iE = ENumericUpDown.Value

    iT = iI + iE

    dI = (iI / iT) * 100
    dE = (iE / iT) * 100
    Dim result As New Result
    result.dI = dI
    result.dE = dE
    Return result
End Function
```

Then using it

```
Dim result As Result = GCalc()
Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.Clear()
Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddXY(0, result.dI)
```

Comment: So my "INumericUpDown_ValueChanged" will be something like this?:
`Private Sub INumericUpDown_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles INumericUpDown.ValueChanged
    'Clear any existing datapoint for that series and add the new data point when the numericupdown value is changed.
    Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.Clear()
    Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddXY(0, Result di)
End Sub`
Is that right?

Comment: Aha! Works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**1** Change your

```
Public Sub GCalc()
```

to a Function

```
Public Function GCalc() as Double
```

and return your value like this:

```
Public Function GCalc()
    'your existing code...
  return di
End Sub
```

than you can call your function

```
Dim di = Gcalc()
```

---

**2** or use a byref value:

```
Public Sub GCalc(ByRef dI As Double, ByRef dE As Double)
    Dim iI As Integer
    Dim iE As Integer
    Dim iT As Integer
    'Dim dI, dE As Double   'For chart datapoints

    iI = INumericUpDown.Value
    iE = ENumericUpDown.Value

    iT = iI + iE

    dI = (iI / iT) * 100
    dE = (iE / iT) * 100
End Sub
```

than call

```
'Declare di & de..
Dim dI as double
Dim dE as double

'Now fill the variables...
GCalc(byRef dI, byRef dE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution is store the value on global variables, because you need 2 values not only 1, so its better than using functions.

```
    Dim dI, dE As Double  = 0.00

    Public Sub GCalc()
        Dim iI As Integer      
        Dim iE As Integer      
        Dim iT As Integer     

        iI = INumericUpDown.Value
        iE = ENumericUpDown.Value

        iT = iI + iE

        dI = (iI / iT) * 100
        dE = (iE / iT) * 100

    End Sub



  Private Sub INumericUpDown_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles INumericUpDown.ValueChanged
 GCalc()
        'Clear any existing datapoint for that series and add the new data point when the numericupdown value is changed.
        Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.Clear()
        Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddXY(0, dI)
    End Sub
```